# gorilla/mux next handler in middleware is nil

Tags: go, mux

I have a custom middleware, and I passed a parameter to the middleware, but when I started the server, I got an `NPE`:

```golang
func SetMigrater(mgt dmigrate.Migrater) mux.MiddlewareFunc {
    return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            r = httputil.WithValue(r, dmigrate.DockerMigraterKey, mgt)
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)  // next is nil ! panic here. middleware/inject.go:57
        })
    }
}
```

RequestID middleware:

```golang
14  func RequestID(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
15      return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
16          id := uuidutil.GenerateWithoutHyphen()
17          r = r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), RequestIdKey, id))
18          w.Header().Add(RequestIdKey, id)
19          next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
20      })
21  }
```

Stack trace:

```
2021/09/13 10:39:54 runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
2021/09/13 10:39:54 goroutine 502 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack(0xc001008aa0, 0x1, 0x1)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x9f
github.com/gorilla/handlers.recoveryHandler.log(0x2210e60, 0xc00100e7e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0xc001008aa0, 0x1, 0x1)
    /app/vendor/github.com/gorilla/handlers/recovery.go:89 +0x7e
github.com/gorilla/handlers.recoveryHandler.ServeHTTP.func1(0x22316e8, 0xc00100b680, 0x2210e60, 0xc00100e7e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1)
    /app/vendor/github.com/gorilla/handlers/recovery.go:74 +0xe5
panic(0x1b59240, 0x2f8e960)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:965 +0x1b9
.../server/http/handlers/middleware.SetMigrater.func1.1(0x22316e8, 0xc00100b680, 0xc000563300)
    .../server/http/handlers/middleware/inject.go:57 +0x83
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00100e780, 0x22316e8, 0xc00100b680, 0xc000563300)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2069 +0x44
.../server/http/handlers/middleware.SetAmqpMessager.func1.1(0x22316e8, 0xc00100b680, 0xc000563200)
    .../server/http/handlers/middleware/inject.go:48 +0xab
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00100e7b0, 0x22316e8, 0xc00100b680, 0xc000563200)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2069 +0x44
.../server/http/handlers/middleware.SetGrpcService.func1.1(0x22316e8, 0xc00100b680, 0xc000563100)
    .../server/http/handlers/middleware/inject.go:39 +0xa2
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000cd6ec0, 0x22316e8, 0xc00100b680, 0xc000563100)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2069 +0x44
.../server/http/handlers/middleware.SetRegistryClient.func1(0x22316e8, 0xc00100b680, 0xc000563000)
    .../server/http/handlers/middleware/inject.go:31 +0x24d
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000cc5d10, 0x22316e8, 0xc00100b680, 0xc000563000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2069 +0x44
.../server/http/handlers/middleware.SetDBHandler.func1.1(0x22316e8, 0xc00100b680, 0xc000562f00)
    .../server/http/handlers/middleware/inject.go:22 +0xab
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00100e7e0, 0x22316e8, 0xc00100b680, 0xc000562f00)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2069 +0x44
github.com/gorilla/handlers.recoveryHandler.ServeHTTP(0x2210e60, 0xc00100e7e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x22316e8, 0xc00100b680, 0xc000562f00)
    /app/vendor/github.com/gorilla/handlers/recovery.go:78 +0xce
.../server/http/handlers/middleware.RequestID.func1(0x22316e8, 0xc00100b680, 0xc000562e00)
    .../server/http/handlers/middleware/request_id.go:19 +0x270
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000cc5d28, 0x22316e8, 0xc00100b680, 0xc000562e00)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2069 +0x44
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc0001db200, 0x22316e8, 0xc00100b680, 0xc000562c00)
    /app/vendor/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:210 +0xd3
github.com/felixge/httpsnoop.CaptureMetrics.func1(0x22316e8, 0xc00100b680)
    /app/vendor/github.com/felixge/httpsnoop/capture_metrics.go:29 +0x4c
github.com/felixge/httpsnoop.CaptureMetricsFn(0x2230398, 0xc000cce1c0, 0xc000dbd848, 0xc000da7880, 0x203000, 0x7fba9ad1c190)
    /app/vendor/github.com/felixge/httpsnoop/capture_metrics.go:76 +0x20a
github.com/felixge/httpsnoop.CaptureMetrics(0x220ab20, 0xc0001db200, 0x2230398, 0xc000cce1c0, 0xc000562c00, 0x7fba9ac341d0, 0x800, 0x5)
    /app/vendor/github.com/felixge/httpsnoop/capture_metrics.go:28 +0x7d
e.coding.net/codingcorp/coding-artifacts/internal/server/docker_core/server/http/handlers/middleware.Logging.func1(0x2230398, 0xc000cce1c0, 0xc000562c00)
    /app/internal/server/docker_core/server/http/handlers/middleware/logging.go:15 +0x6f
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000ece960, 0x2230398, 0xc000cce1c0, 0xc000562c00)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2069 +0x44
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0006582a0, 0x2230398, 0xc000cce1c0, 0xc000562c00)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2887 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc000dac780, 0x2239e70, 0xc000cdbd00)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1952 +0x8cd
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:3013 +0x39b
```

Middlewares:

```golang
func (app *App) useMiddlewares() {
    app.router.Use(middleware.RequestID)
    app.router.Use(handlers.RecoveryHandler(handlers.PrintRecoveryStack(true)))
    app.router.Use(
        middleware.SetDBHandler(app.db),
        middleware.SetRegistryClient,
        middleware.SetGrpcService(app.grpcService),
    )

    app.router.Use(middleware.SetAmqpMessager(messager))
    app.router.Use(middleware.SetMigrater(migrater))
}
```

More information:

new router:

```golang
// RouterWithPrefix builds a gorilla router with a configured prefix
// on all routes.
func RouterWithPrefix(prefix string) *mux.Router {
    rootRouter := mux.NewRouter()
    router := rootRouter
    if prefix != "" {
        router = router.PathPrefix(prefix).Subrouter()
    }

    router.StrictSlash(true)

    for _, descriptor := range routeDescriptors {
        router.Path(descriptor.Path).Name(descriptor.Name)
    }

    return rootRouter
}
```

Serving this http server:

```golang
func (app *App) ListenAndServe(port int) error {
    svc := &service{grpcService: app.grpcService}

    // base
    r := app.router.PathPrefix("/v2").Subrouter()
    r.Use(
        middleware.Whitelist,
        middleware.PassInternalRequest,
        middleware.Authenticate(app.grpcService),
        middleware.SetArtInfo(app.grpcService),
    )

    // /v2/
    r.HandleFunc("/", proxyutil.ServeHTTP).Methods(http.MethodGet)

    // other handlers ...

    loggedHandler := middleware.Logging(app.router)
    app.server = &http.Server{
        Addr:    httputil.Addr(port),
        Handler: loggedHandler,
    }

    log.Info("Serving the HTTP server successfully", zap.Int("port", port))
    if err := app.server.ListenAndServe(); err != nil && !errors.IgnoreError(err) {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Test:

```sh
curl -v http://localhost:8080/v2/
500 Internal Server Error
```

My go version: `go version go1.16.5 linux/amd64`

`gorilla/mux` version: `github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0`

I'm really confused why this next handler is nil ..

And because it is `nil`, my next handlers of the router will never be execute, include my real handlers, not even middlewares.

If I have something wrong? I couldn't figure this out.

Comment: Do not post images of text.

Comment: Please share [mcve] as text.

Comment: @JuanChan can you show what is in file `../middleware/inject.go` on line `60`?

Comment: @Volker I've changed images to text

Comment: @mkopriva I've updated this post, and pointed out where the panic happened. You'll see `next.ServeHTTP(w, r)  // next is nil ! panic here`

Comment: @mkopriva `next.ServeHTTP(w, r)  // next is nil ! panic here`  next is nil

Comment: @JuanChan what's on `.../server/http/handlers/middleware/request_id.go:19`?

Comment: @mkopriva updated. `request_id.go:19` is `next.ServeHTTP(w, r)`

Comment: @JuanChan Are you getting the error for every request to any path? And can you show how you're registering the handlers of those paths that are causing this panic? You've shown only middleware so far, but for all we know you could be doing `router.Handle("/", nil)`.

Comment: @mkopriva Updated, I added more information about the router. I only got the `NPE` in the final middleware: `SetMigrater` - `inject:57`, previous are OK.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, I've solved this problem.

I use [alice](https://github.com/justinas/alice) to wrap middlewares and my handler:

```golang
func (app *App) addMiddlewares() http.Handler {
    return alice.New(
        middleware.Logging,
        middleware.RequestID,
        // some other middlewares ...
        middleware.SetMigrater(migrater),
    ).Then(app.router)
}
```

```golang
func (app *App) ListenAndServe(port int) error {
    svc := &service{}

    // base
    r := app.router.PathPrefix("/v2").Subrouter()
    r.Use(
        middleware.Whitelist,
        middleware.PassInternalRequest,
        middleware.Authenticate(app.grpcService),
        middleware.SetArtInfo(app.grpcService),
    )

    // /v2/
    r.HandleFunc("/", proxyutil.ServeHTTP).Methods(http.MethodGet)
    // wrap the handler
    handler := app.addMiddlewares()
    app.server = &http.Server{
        Addr:    httputil.Addr(port),
        Handler: handler,
    }

    log.Info("Serving the HTTP server successfully", zap.Int("port", port))
    if err := app.server.ListenAndServe(); err != nil && !errors.IgnoreError(err) {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

And one important thing what I did was change the way to new a mux router from `router := RouterWithPrefix("")` to `router := mux.NewRouter()`.

This could avoid 404 from my handlers.

Then, no `NPE` anymore, peace and love.

Thanks everyone again :)